Decoding Windows' Clipboard Pinned Items' File
So I have a Windows 11 PC with my password being saved in the clipboard as a pinned item, I forgot to write it down and after enabling my Microsoft account to windows I miss clicked using pin and chose enter Microsoft password everytime, now I have no access to PC but I managed to get my clipboard's pinned items to my laptop with connecting its ssd to my laptop, i replaced the clipboard files, there are some shown items in my laptop's clipboard but no content is visible and they don't paste the text (password), I wanted to know how can I decode/read/decrypt those files, they names seems to be repetitive on every other pc called "TG9jYWxl" and "VGV4dA=="
I tried contacting Microsoft, safeboot and bunch of normal ways to fix this but failed due to my Microsoft account having 2fa (which is stored on locked pc) and safeboot needing Microsoft password
